# Mongoose slow select particular field that not in model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination

When I select some field (b) that not in the Mongoose model by using Mongoose Paginate plugin like this

```
const transactionData = await TransactionModel.paginate(condition, {
            select: "a b c d e f g",
            sort: {createdDate: -1},
            lean: true,
            page: page,
            limit: limit,
            populate: {
                path: 'memberId',
                select: '_id username'
            }
        })
```

It's so slow when query. and then I try to remove the [b] field. It seems really fast more than the previous one. I need to know why.